# different elemens with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

By AJAX I get JSON:

```
data : [
    {
     "type":"h2",
     "PCDATA":"Title"
    },
    {
     "type":"p",
     "PCDATA":"First paragraph."
    },
    {
     "type":"li",
     "PCDATA":"list node"
    },
    {
     "type":"p",
     "PCDATA":"First paragraph."
    }
]
```

and now I need to generate such HTML:

```
<h2>Title</h2>
<p>First paragraph.</p>
<ul>
    <li>list node</li>
</ul>
<p>First paragraph.</p>
```

Can I do it using `ng-repeat` directive? How can I generate different HTML elements using one `ng-repeat` loop?

Comment: Use ng-switch and/or [ng-if](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive:ngIf) (if using Angular 1.1.5) inside your ng-repeat to conditionally add the appropriate HTML element.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can just use ng-repeat because I don't think something like `<{{elem.type}}>{{elem.PCDATA}}</{{elem.type}}>` inside ng-repeat would work.

Here's a fiddle for how to do it in controller: http://jsfiddle.net/terebentina/H3vQ9/3/ 
I simulated the ajax call with $timeout.

However, note that this is at the border of good practice - you shouldn't manipulate html inside your controller but in this case you could argue that you're manipulating data.

A better way to do it would be with a directive that would loop over your data, similar with how I did it in my example

Comment: Thanks, it is one of cases. I use custom directive.